# How to limit/control evolution IMAP to not download mail attachments bigger than X bytes?

Tags: evolution

Is there a way to limit or control evolution IMAP to not download attachments that are bigger than X bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution is to add the rule ("**Message**"->"**Create Rule**")
[image: see rule]
Add Condition:

1. Attachments = Exist
2. Size(kB) = X000

Add Action:

- Stop Processing
- or Move to Folder (and exclude this folder from synchronization)

Comment: isnt this rule applied at the client side?  i.e. after the attachment has been downloaded?

Comment: Yes, this is client-side rule , but this rule applied after downloading message's header only, before processing body and attachments

Comment: ok - add this comment to your answer.

Comment: Great, it worked :)